# How should I add empty data to the database?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a variable for example:

```
$data_empty_on_this_case
```

What case is the correct to add empty data?

```
$data_empty_on_this_case = "0";
$data_empty_on_this_case = 0;
$data_empty_on_this_case = "NULL";
$data_empty_on_this_case = NULL;
$data_empty_on_this_case = "";
```

Im using PHP 7.4

Comment: what's correct is whatever you actually need. `null` is the purest form of expressing "nothing". e.g. 0 could feasibly be a valid value in some situations. It all depends. In a database though, NULL is _normally_ what you'd use

Comment: @ADyson That value will be sometimes empty and sometimes with data, the quotes influence?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Quote marks are used if the value is a string. If it's not a string (e.g. it's a number, perhaps), then don't use quote marks. and NULL doesn't have quote marks round it (in PHP) when you specify that.

Comment: It's worth remarking too that NULL really means "no data" rather than "empty data" ...e.g `""` is often known as the "empty string" because although it contains no text or characters, it's also not NULL - and therefore it does have a value. _something_ is there, even though it's essentially empty, but it's not the same as nothing.

Answer (score 1):

By using NULL you can distinguish between "put no data" and "put empty data".

- A LENGTH of `NULL` is `NULL`, a LENGTH of an empty string is `0`.
- `NULL`s are sorted before the empty strings.

In more detail, answer your question in the database if you have Default `NULL` then insert `NULL` otherwise Insert like this $data_empty_on_this_case = "";

```
$data_empty_on_this_case = 0; [ For integer datatype ]

$data_empty_on_this_case = "NULL"; [ For varchar/char datatype ]
```